# How can I hide a div containing a select field, without resetting its selected value?

Tags: javascript

The user can toggle sections of the page and in some of them, there is a `select` field with a value selected.
When the function below is run and that section in which the `select` field exists, that comes back with no value selected.

I guess I understood that I should use `hidden` instead, but that would keep the structure in the `DOM` and since this tends to grow a bit, it would get slow overtime, so I would tend to use `display:none` instead.

Do I really need to get all options from the `select` in question and restore them at the end with the one selected showing?

```
function showSectionContainer(sectionId) {
  const sectionContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.section-container');
  const targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);

  sectionContainers.forEach(container => {
    container.style.display = container.id !== sectionId ? "none" : "";
  });

  if (targetSection) {
    targetSection.style.display = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html in your question.

Comment: Why do you need the `if (targetSection)` block? That's already done by the conditional in `forEach()`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Changing the style of the container shouldn't have any effect on the selected option. I suspect your have something else that's replacing the HTML of the `<select>`

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar and sorry for my poor example. I did have another function re-building the `select` options. I did set a criteria there to check if it wasn't populated yet and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just to use display none style property

```js
function showSectionContainer(sectionId)
{
  const sectionContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.section-container');

  sectionContainers.forEach(container =>
  {
    if (container.id === sectionId)
    {
      container.style.removeProperty('display');
    }
    else
    {
      container.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = this;
  const formElements = form.elements;

  for (let i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
  {
    const element = formElements[i];
    console.log(element);
    console.log(element.name + ': ' + element.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="section-container" id="section1" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <select name="Numeric select">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2" selected>Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="section-container" id="section2" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <select name="Literal select">
      <option value="optionA">Option A</option>
      <option value="optionB">Option B</option>
      <option value="optionC" selected>Option C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button onclick="showSectionContainer('section1')" type="button">Show Section 1</button>
  <button onclick="showSectionContainer('section2')" type="button">Show Section 2</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="as-console-wrapper" id="formResults"></div>
```

Comment: I actually had another function clearing the `select` field and causing that behavior. Your answer, however, got used as the logic is more straight forward. Thanks!